Windows 10 DSCP always translated to WMM AC default CoS/TID/UP
I have trouble with understanding (and fixing) Windows 10 approach on translating DSCP QoS to WMM AC CoS.
No matter if I use hrping/iperf3 or the way of measurement (STA->AP or AP->STA) the stations always have proper DSCP and wrong 802.11 priority - set to Best Effort.
I've already enabled QoS in registry and tried using polices with PriorityValue80021Action, but without any success.
AP is responding with proper CoS due to DSCP settings, but my main goal is to be able to set priority on 80211 level in stations in order to conduct research about collisions at my university.
Wireshark screen with Priority, TID and DSCP
